# "Precompiling assets failed" when pushing a Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am taking a Ruby on Rails course and I am trying to push an app to Heroku. I've searched through older StackOverflow posts about this same issue, but none of those suggestions are working for me. Below is the log of my attempt. I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

I'm being told to add more text. the main errors seem to be:

"Precompiling assets failed"

"Pre-receive hook declined"

```
ID 52540144-6b6d-4959-95a0-b9350d45a774
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.5). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Fetching rake 12.3.1
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Fetching minitest 5.11.3
       Installing minitest 5.11.3
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Installing rake 12.3.1
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Fetching builder 3.2.3
       Installing builder 3.2.3
       Fetching erubi 1.7.1
       Installing erubi 1.7.1
       Fetching mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Installing mini_portile2 2.3.0
       Fetching crass 1.0.4
       Installing crass 1.0.4
       Fetching rack 2.0.5
       Fetching nio4r 2.3.1
       Installing nio4r 2.3.1 with native extensions
       Installing rack 2.0.5
       Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.3
       Fetching mini_mime 1.0.1
       Installing mini_mime 1.0.1
       Fetching arel 9.0.0
       Installing arel 9.0.0
       Fetching mimemagic 0.3.2
       Fetching execjs 2.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Fetching msgpack 1.2.4
       Installing mimemagic 0.3.2
       Installing msgpack 1.2.4 with native extensions
       Fetching popper_js 1.14.3
       Installing popper_js 1.14.3
       Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
       Fetching ffi 1.9.25
       Installing ffi 1.9.25 with native extensions
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Fetching method_source 0.9.0
       Installing method_source 0.9.0
       Fetching thor 0.20.0
       Installing thor 0.20.0
       Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
       Installing multi_json 1.13.1
       Fetching pg 1.1.3
       Installing pg 1.1.3 with native extensions
       Fetching puma 3.12.0
       Installing puma 3.12.0 with native extensions
       Fetching tilt 2.0.8
       Installing tilt 2.0.8
       Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
       Fetching i18n 1.1.1
       Installing i18n 1.1.1
       Fetching nokogiri 1.8.5
       Installing nokogiri 1.8.5 with native extensions
       Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.0
       Installing websocket-driver 0.7.0 with native extensions
       Fetching mail 2.7.1
       Installing mail 2.7.1
       Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
       Installing rack-test 1.1.0
       Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
       Installing sprockets 3.7.2
       Fetching autoprefixer-rails 9.3.1
       Installing autoprefixer-rails 9.3.1
       Fetching uglifier 4.1.19
       Installing uglifier 4.1.19
       Fetching marcel 0.3.3
       Installing marcel 0.3.3
       Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Fetching bootsnap 1.3.2
       Installing bootsnap 1.3.2 with native extensions
       Fetching rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Installing rb-inotify 0.9.10
       Fetching turbolinks 5.2.0
       Installing turbolinks 5.2.0
       Fetching activesupport 5.2.1
       Installing activesupport 5.2.1
       Fetching loofah 2.2.3
       Installing loofah 2.2.3
       Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
       Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Fetching globalid 0.4.1
       Installing globalid 0.4.1
       Fetching activemodel 5.2.1
       Fetching jbuilder 2.7.0
       Installing activemodel 5.2.1
       Installing jbuilder 2.7.0
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
       Fetching sass 3.6.0
       Fetching activejob 5.2.1
       Installing activejob 5.2.1
       Installing sass 3.6.0
       Fetching activerecord 5.2.1
       Fetching actionview 5.2.1
       Installing activerecord 5.2.1
       Installing actionview 5.2.1
       Fetching actionpack 5.2.1
       Installing actionpack 5.2.1
       Fetching bootstrap 4.1.3
       Installing bootstrap 4.1.3
       Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
       Fetching actioncable 5.2.1
       Installing actioncable 5.2.1
       Fetching actionmailer 5.2.1
       Installing actionmailer 5.2.1
       Fetching activestorage 5.2.1
       Installing activestorage 5.2.1
       Fetching railties 5.2.1
       Installing railties 5.2.1
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
       Fetching jquery-rails 4.3.3
       Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Fetching rails 5.2.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Installing rails 5.2.1
       Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
       Installing jquery-rails 4.3.3
       Bundle complete! 19 Gemfile dependencies, 66 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from sass:

       Ruby Sass is deprecated and will be unmaintained as of 26 March 2019.

       * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
         primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

       * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
         sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

       * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
         http://sass.logdown.com/posts/7081811

       Bundle completed (47.12s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.5). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       The latest bundler is 1.17.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
       I, [2018-10-31T14:05:58.213666 #1419]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/public/assets/bicycle-b0065f34bb7db6b7b0a5cf8d177e85276f69b39e791b5fd72a245e8b90e0cc43.jpg
       I, [2018-10-31T14:06:05.048362 #1419]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/public/assets/application-b2b98178b68108062edcf84d640b496d914a3dab78c660f799ab4c8a54064fcd.js
       I, [2018-10-31T14:06:05.048648 #1419]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/public/assets/application-b2b98178b68108062edcf84d640b496d914a3dab78c660f799ab4c8a54064fcd.js.gz
       rake aborted!
       Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
       Load paths:
         /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/assets/stylesheets
         /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/assets/stylesheets
       (sass):1
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:44:in `import'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:310:in `visit_import'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/engine.rb:290:in `render'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

       Caused by:
       Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
       Load paths:
         /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/assets/stylesheets
         /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/assets/stylesheets
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:65:in `import'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:310:in `visit_import'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/engine.rb:290:in `render'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_d87edff4795e58683aa5e3626de5a3f7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rails 2.0+**

---

It's because you're using `bootstrap-sprockets` but don't have the `bootstrap-sass` gem installed.

Basically add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

Then import the variables in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`:

```
// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Last, if you're using a `scss` you need to change all of your `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree` to `@import` in order to import Sass files. You can find more detailed installation instructions here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

**Rails 4.0+**

---

For newer versions of rails follow this documentation: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails

1. add `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'` to your Gemfile
2. add `@import "bootstrap";` to your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`
3. remove all the `*= require` and `*= require_tree` statements from the Sass file, instead use `@import`
4. add `gem 'jquery-rails'` to your Gemfile

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added those gems to the gemfile but got an error that said there was a conflict between sass rails 3.2 and gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0’ being in the same file, so I deleted the 5.0 line.

I tried to push to Heroku again but got the same line. The log is too long to post, but the bottom looks like this: 
remote: ! Push rejected to wicked-barrow-70229.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/wicked-barrow-70229.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/wicked-barrow-70229.git'

Comment: No don't delete the 5.0 line! If you're using a new version of rails follow this documentation instead: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails and undo the changes I suggested earlier.

Comment: Does any of this change if I have application.css and not application.scss?

Comment: Yes there are important changes. You will need to change your `application.css` to `application.scss`, and remove `*= require` and `*= require_tree` like in step 3.

Comment: I renamed application.css to application.scss, removed the *=requireds, added @import "bootstrap"; to the top of application.scss, and I'm receiving the following error when I try to bundle install (I thought bundle install was necessary whenever I update the gemfile)
_________________________________________________________
There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: sass-rails (>= 3.2) and sass-rails (~> 5.0). Bundler cannot continue.

Comment: Like I said, undo the changes I suggested earlier. You forgot to delete `gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'`. Also please but back the 5.0 line if you haven't.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if you're all set